# Syntax error when I try to import any module

Tags: python

```
C:\Users\sanji\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/sanji/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sanji\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\file.py", line 1, in
import tkinter
File "C:\Users\sanji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1769
if self._name in self.master.children:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you edit or _play around_  with the `tkinter.py` file?

Comment: What is the name of the file your editing, if it is Tkinter then you need to rename your current file to something else.

Comment: @Aiyush As you can see in the traceback, the script is called `file.py`.

Comment: Is that your whole file? Is there anything under the if statement?

Comment: I can also confirm that line 1769 for me in `__init__.py` of `tkinter` is not the one mentioned in the error.

Answer (score 0):

In the `__init__.py` file for `Tkinter`, versions `3.9.2` through `3.9.5` inclusive have that statement appearing only on lines `2556` and `2581`. See [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.5/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py), for example.

In the `3.9` variants before that, it's on various similar lines, around `2552` and `2577` give or take a couple of lines for small file changes.

It has *never* been anywhere near line `1769` in any of the `3.9` releases (including the release candidates).

So, given it's complaining about the file in the path containing `...Python\Python39\lib\...`, I don't think we need to look at any other versions. I would say it's a safe bet that the file has become corrupted somehow.

You should check that file for validity and, if there's something wrong with it (probable), you may need to re-install Python to fix it. We can probably only *speculate* as to how it became corrupted (if indeed it did).

Maybe someone accidentally edited it or maybe you have a problematic disk. It's hard to say without seeing the entire file (or at least some twenty lines around the one the error's reported on).